# Passage: usage example

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, bayesian-networks

Has anyone used [Passage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/passage), the PArallel SAmpler GEnerator?

Potentially it could be very useful to me, but the only documentation I found is the three line README on Github (https://github.com/cscherrer/passage), and the terse API on Hackage.

A simple example of how to run it would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a high level, Passage has two important monads to keep in mind: `BayesianNetwork` and `BayesianSimulator`.

First, you build a model in the BayesianNetwork monad:

```
myModel :: Int -> BayesianNetwork (Node, Node, [Node])
myModel n = do
  mu <- normal 0 0.001
  tau <- improperScale
  xs <- replicateM n $ normal mu tau
  return (mu, tau, xs)
```

This is specified as a generative model, so anything that is not random (here the number of data points `n`) must be passed as a parameter. Alternatively, we could have put a distribution on `n`.

Next, we build a simulator that calls the model:

```
mySim :: [Double] -> BayesianSimulator ()
mySim xs0 = do
  setThreadNum 4
  let n = length xs0
  (mu, tau, xs) <- model $ myModel n
  forM (zip xs xs0) $ \(x, x0) -> observe x x0
  monitor mu
  monitor tau
```

Finally, take some data:

```
xs0 = [1, -1, 2, 2, 2, -2]
```

and run the simluator:

```
main = genSimulator "myExample" (mySim xs0)
```

This creates a new directory `myExample` with OpenMP code for the sampler.